# Update JTextField on button press

Tags: java, swing

I have an `if` statement on a button that when clicked will change a `JTextField` to £35.00. I also want to be able to use a `JRadioButton` that when clicked will change the `JTextField` to £70.00.

Code:

```
sesh1.addActionListener(e2->{
if (sesh1.isSelected())
tSesh1.setText("35.00");
});
```

tSesh1 is the text field.

Also:

```
//ActionListener for saving session info to text file
JButton submitInvoice = new JButton ("Submit");
sPanel.add(submitInvoice);
submitInvoice.addActionListener(e9->{
try{
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("RegInvoice_0to2.txt",true));
bw.write("---------------Booking Invoice---------------");
bw.write("\r\n");
bw.write("---------------0 To 2 Year Olds--------------");
bw.write("\r\n");       
bw.write("[Sessions Selected]");
bw.write("\r\n");
bw.write("All Day: £"); bw.write(tSesh1.getText());
bw.write(" On");
//
//Displays the days selected for All Day Sessions
if(mon1.isSelected()){
bw.write(" Monday"); bw.write(" ");
tSesh1.setText("70.00"); // This wont change the text field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made this little demo **taking your sentences** related to `JRadioButtons` being selected and affecting a `JTextField`.

It fulfills your requirements. They are your own sentences.

> I have an if statement on a button that when clicked will change a
>   JTextField to £35.00. I also want to be able to use a JRadioButton
>   that when clicked will change the JTextField to £70.00.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JRadioTest extends JFrame {

public JRadioTest() {

    setSize(500,500);
    setTitle("JRadioTest");
    setResizable(true);

    initComponents();

    setVisible(true);

}

private void initComponents() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("My text field");

    panel.add(label);

    JTextField tSesh1 = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(tSesh1);

    JRadioButton sesh1 = new JRadioButton("35.00");

    sesh1.addActionListener(e -> {
           if (sesh1.isSelected()) {
               tSesh1.setText("35.00");
           }
    });

    panel.add(sesh1);

    JRadioButton mon1 = new JRadioButton("70.00");
    panel.add(mon1);

    JButton submitInvoice = new JButton("Submit");

    submitInvoice.addActionListener(e -> {
         if (mon1.isSelected()) {
               tSesh1.setText("70.00");
         }
    });

    panel.add(mon1);
    panel.add(submitInvoice);

    this.add(panel);

}


public static void main(String args[]){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JRadioTest();

        }
    });   

}  

}
```

Test it.

If your `JTextField` is not showing "70.00" when you select `mon1` and press `submitInvoice`, is probably because an exception is being thrown when you try to write to the file.